# Good Speed but slow browsing

Tags: dns, browser, download, packet, fiber

I installed a new Fiber connection of 30 Mbps up/down speed. I tested download some files on the connection the download speed is very much stable and almost 30 Mbps but the problem arrives when I do browsing. Sometimes a simple and optimized website like **YouTube** takes 5-10 seconds to load and sometimes it loads in a blink of an eye. This happens like every single minute.
I tried [speedtest](https://www.speedtest.net/) and the speeds are fine there but the issue is with browsing only.

[image: speedtest]

**Things I tried:**

- Changed LAN Cable
- Switched to WiFi
- Tested on different PC
- Changed Router
- Released, Renew and Flush DNS

Nothing works for me. The ISP is a local company that works in a very specific area. They don't have people with good technical expertise, which is why they are also unable to figure this out.

The websites sometimes load very slow, sometimes gives a message "**This site can't be reached** and sometimes give some kind of DNS issue (very rare)

Yesterday, I tried to troubleshoot the issue and this was the error Windows 10 detected.

[image: Troubleshoot]

I tried troubleshooting again a few times but Windows couldn't find any error again.

I tried changing my DNS to Google (8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4), that too didn't work.

**I am using Huawei Router (HG8245)**

Comment: My GUESS is either an mtu issue (try setting your mtu to 1476 on your pc and see if the issue goes away - that will help isolate the issue) or that the issue is on the ISP side. It could be a very crude QoS issue (and idps often trat speedtest sites differently - no honor among thieves) or conceivably an issue with the configuration of your port.

Comment: @davidgo that's alot of technical terms, i am not much familiar with networking, if you can explain it in simple words please.

Comment: See [Change DNS Windows](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-change-your-pcs-dns-settings-windows-10). It is likely that your ISP has configured your device to forward DNS requests to their router/gateway, which has problems handling heavy loads.

Comment: I tried changed DNS, that also doesn't work

Comment: Can you provide more specific information?  You changed your DNS provider to what exactly?  [edit] your question instead of submitting a temporary comment

Comment: @Palladen Sorry, no! Im a Linux system administrator (and dont have a Windows pc!) but you should be able to Goofle "mtu windows setting" and follow what it says. MTU sets the maximum size if a chunk of data and can cause weird problems like you describe if your  mtu is to large. Nothing you can do about other causes other then get your ISP obto it or change providers.

Comment: What is your router exact model? Do you know how long is the cable of the ISP to the building? What kind of cable is it? (Add to your answering comment `@harrymc` for me to be notified.)

Comment: @harrymc Router is Huawei HG8245, the cable isn't long, I'm not sure about the exact length but it will be around 35-40 meters. It's a Optic Fiber.

Comment: Optic fiber speed should be way above 30 Mbps.

Comment: @harrymc Even in the US there are fiber optic providers that only provide 30mbps(Frontier). The service location is probably Pakistan, so I can't speak to their situation with 100% certainty, but the speed itself isn't concerning in my opinion.

Comment: I don't think it's the speed issue, as the downloads or uploads are pretty fine and fast.